# Can't update Nexus S. Stuck at "waiting for download"

Tags: updates, samsung-nexus-s, 4.2-jelly-bean

I want to upgrade my Operating system (Nexus S I9250) which currently is Android 4.1 . My cell is not rooted and I have never tampered with the android system shipped, always upgraded it though. Right now, it says "Waiting for Download" but the progress bar never goes ahead.

Comment: According to the [Nexus Factory Image Site](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images) the Nexus S was only updated to 4.1.1 there shouldn't be anything else newer available.

Comment: yeah.. but why is it showing an  update in the android system update ? plus it could be an updated build of 4.1.1, although the update is of 95.8 MB.

Comment: Have you tried restarting your phone?

Comment: @ZnewmaN earlier I restarted but it didn't work. Now it works. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restarting your phone should resolve the issue.